# Print Individual Elements of List

Tags: python

I've an array of this format:

```
val = [[1302, 303, 168, 536],
 [1424, 360, 226, 677],
 [776, 321, 194, 509],
 [1066, 276, 191, 571]]
```

I'm extracting first and second element of the array in the following way:

```
x = [col for col in list(zip(*val))[0]]
y = [col for col in list(zip(*val))[1]]
```

Creating an empty set:

```
points = set()
```

Creating a tuple with combination of list:

```
center = tuple(zip(x,y))
```

Appending the list in the point dataset:

```
points.add(center)
```

Finally trying to print one list at a time:

```
for point in points:
    print(point)
```

I'm getting the following result:

```
((1302, 303), (1424, 360), (776, 321), (1066, 276))
```

But I want it should print:

First, `(1302, 303)`

Second, `(1424, 360)`

and so on.

Can someone please guide me how to do it?

Thanks!

Comment: why not just `for i in val:
    print(tuple(i[:2]))`?

Comment: This is because I just gave 1 `val`. There might be multiple vals I need to keep track of them.

Comment: Why not simply `x = list(zip(*val))[0]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find this too complicated:

```
x = [col for col in list(zip(*val))[0]]
y = [col for col in list(zip(*val))[1]]
```

Instead, you could do:

```
x = [col[0] for col in val]
y = [col[1] for col in val]
```

Then, create your points data structure:

```
points = set([(i, j) for i, j in zip(x, y)])
```

Print your points:

```
for point in points:
    print(point)
```

Comment: Perfect!! Thanks a ton Neb!

Comment: Stackoverflow is not allowing me. I've to wait for 4 mins. Will do in a moment.

Answer (score 1):

Just use a double for-loop

```
#Iterate over the set
for point in points:
    #Iterate on each point
    for item in point:
        print(item)
```

This will output

```
(1302, 303)
(1424, 360)
(776, 321)
(1066, 276)
```

To print it in a single loop, you need to modify your `points` set to a 1-D list

```
val = [[1302, 303, 168, 536],
 [1424, 360, 226, 677],
 [776, 321, 194, 509],
 [1066, 276, 191, 571]]


x = [col for col in list(zip(*val))[0]]
y = [col for col in list(zip(*val))[1]]
points = set()
center = tuple(zip(x,y))
points.add(center)

#Convert set to a 1-D list
points = list(*points)

for point in points:
    print(point)
```

This will output

```
(1302, 303)
(1424, 360)
(776, 321)
(1066, 276)
```

Or a one-liner `print` without loops

```
val = [[1302, 303, 168, 536],
 [1424, 360, 226, 677],
 [776, 321, 194, 509],
 [1066, 276, 191, 571]]


x = [col for col in list(zip(*val))[0]]
y = [col for col in list(zip(*val))[1]]
points = set()
center = tuple(zip(x,y))
points.add(center)

#One liner print
print(*list(*points), sep='\n')
```

Comment: Thanks Devesh! But can't we do it one step? But modification of previous code. I'm new to python, so don't know how to fix it.

Comment: But why in one step, your `point` is a tuple of tuples, and we need to iterate over the tuple to obtain individual tuples! @Beta

Comment: Okay I made an update to the answer, which should allow you to print it in a single for loop! Or even in a single line using a print statement, without modifying your code at all @Beta

Comment: The objective was not printing, but to work with each elements of the dataset. Also, unfortunately the print statement is not working. But thanks for your help! I've upvoted your answer.

Comment: Interesting! Which print is not working? The last one or the second last one? You could actually use the `*list(*points)` to make your list of tuples as well, Could you clarify please @Beta :)

Comment: The `*list` one.`print(*list(*points), sep='\n')
          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax`. I'm working with python 3.6. Can't add more comments. So updating here.

Comment: Aah, you using python2 or python3? This worked for me in python3.7, what error did you get? @Beta

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193213/discussion-between-devesh-kumar-singh-and-beta).

Answer (score 1):

You can just iterate over your original list:

```
for x in val:
    print(tuple(x[:2]))
```

Or from your `points` using unpacking and passing `sep`:

```
points = ((1302, 303), (1424, 360), (776, 321), (1066, 276))

print(*points, sep='\n')
# (1302, 303)
# (1424, 360)
# (776, 321) 
# (1066, 276)
```